# NullPointerException when i use a buffered reader

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have this piece of code which reads a file and creates a list of string array to transform into a list of lines and columns. This code is running well but i dont't know why a NullPointerException is thrown. Can you help me ?

```html
private List<String[]> csvToList(String inputFile, String delimiter) {
  
  String line[];
  
  List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<String[]>();
   
  try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile))){
   
   // Gets the first row of the input (Header)
   line = br.readLine().split(delimiter);
   
   if (line.length > 0) lines.add(line);   
   
   while (line.length > 0) {
    line = br.readLine().split(","); 
    
    if (line.length > 0) lines.add(line);  
   }
   
   br.close();
   
  } catch(NullPointerException npe) {
   // Here is thrown a null pointer exception
  } catch(Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }
  
  
  return lines;
 }
```

Comment: Please add exception stack trace

Comment: The exception is not thrown at the place of your comment, it is caught there :)

Comment: you did not check for end of file

Answer (score 0):

In your case, NPE means that you reached the end of file - you need to check for `null` when calling `br.readLine()`:

```
String singleLine;
while((singleLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    line = singleLine.split(",");
    if (line.length > 0) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
}
```